# Why is the account address from metamask coming back as undefined after storing it in useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this piece of code that is connecting to metamask wallet and sets the account address using useState().

```
const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("")
const connectWallet = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install MetaMask.")

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })

      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0])
      console.log(accounts)
      //   TODO:Add conditional statement to check if user has token
      navigate("/portfolio")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)

      throw new Error("No ethereum object")
    }
  }

 console.log("current account", currentAccount)

  const returnCollection = async (currentAccount) => {
    const options = { method: 'GET', headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } };


    fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?asset_owner=${currentAccount}&offset=0&limit=300`, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log("collection owned by current address", response))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));


 useEffect(() => {
   
    returnCollection(currentAccount)
  })
```

The console is logging the account but when I try to pass it in the returnCollection call in useEffect() it comes back as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It seems here, you are doing something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   
    returnCollection(currentAccount)
  })
```

This will run after every rerender or every state change, and also initially when the component is first mounted, when `currentAccount` is "". Initially, current account is "", so you may not want to get the collection from "". Instead, maybe what you can do is create another state variable for the result of the `returnConnection`, and set the state variable to the result of the `returnConnection`, since you typically don't return results from `useEffect`, unless it's a cleanup function. Also, maybe you can check the state of `currentAccount` inside of the `useEffect` to make sure it's not "", before returning the result.